# Sitecore custom contact facet

Tags: xdb

Getting exception on Xdb BuildModel().
Please help me with the below exception.

```
'CollectionModel.Model' threw an exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException'
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    HResult: -2146233036
    HelpLink: null
    InnerException: {"Thread was being aborted."}
    Message: "The type initializer for 'Sitecore.Feature.PageContent.CustomRules.CollectionModel' threw an exception."
    Source: null
    StackTrace: null
    TargetSite: null
    TypeName: "Sitecore.Feature.PageContent.CustomRules.CollectionModel"



    [Serializable]
        [FacetKey(DefaultFacetKey)]
        public class UserProfile : Sitecore.XConnect.Facet
        {
            public UserProfile(string type)
            {
                Type = type;
            }
            public const string DefaultFacetKey = "UserProfile";
            public string Type { get; set; }
        }

        public class CollectionModel
        {
            public static XdbModel Model { get; } = BuildModel();

            private static XdbModel BuildModel()
            {
                XdbModelBuilder modelBuilder = new XdbModelBuilder("DemoModel", new XdbModelVersion(1, 0));

                modelBuilder.ReferenceModel(Sitecore.XConnect.Collection.Model.CollectionModel.Model);
                modelBuilder.DefineFacet<Contact, UserProfile>(UserProfile.DefaultFacetKey);

                return modelBuilder.BuildModel();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Could you paste the code that calls BuildModel()?

Comment: var json = XdbModelWriter.Serialize(CollectionModel.Model);